# Volumes and integration question help.

Tags: integration, volume

**Question**: The diagram shows the region enclosed by the parts of the line $y = x/2$ and $x=3$ and the part of the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=12$. The area is rotated about the $y$ - axis to form a solid. Find the volume of the solid.

Please help, I'm kinda stuck and help would be much appreciated. Thank you so much :)[image: integration and volumes help]

the second diagram is the actual diagram after redrawing it, thanks to the individual that informed me

[image: actual diagram]

Comment: the diagram is ...false. They don't meet at $x = 3$.

Comment: well, that was the question i got given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inner Radius = $3$ and $2y$

Outer Radius = $\sqrt{(12+y^2)}$

Points of intersection = $(0,\frac{3}{2})$ and $(\frac{3}{2},2)$

Volume Enclosed by the region $=\int_a^{b} \pi\left((Outer radius)^2 - (Inner Radius)^2\right)dy$

$$=\int_0^{\frac{3}{2}} \pi\left(12+y^2 - 3^2\right)dy+\int_{\frac{3}{2}}^{2} \pi\left(12+y^2 - 4y^2\right)dy$$

Comment: yes i do recognise your method

Comment: could you please tell me the answer to your solution

Comment: It is $16\pi$. that will be the answer

Comment: The answer that i have to attain is 7(pi)

Comment: I made a calculation error, Yes it is $7\pi$.  The formulation is good to go.

Comment: i have one more query to ask, how did you attain those values for the point of intersection

Comment: Put x = 3, you find y = 3/2  to find the intersection of x = 3 and y = x/2 and to find the intersection of y =x/2 and $x^2-y^2 = 12$, put x = 2y and substitute it in $x^2-y^2=12 => 4y^2-y^2 = 12 => 3y^2 = 12 => y^2 = 4 => y = 2$

Answer (score 1):

The $x$-intercept of the hyperbola is: $x = 2\sqrt{3}$. We can split it into $2$ solids, and the first one goes from $x = 3 \to x = 2\sqrt{3}$, while the second goes from $x = 2\sqrt{3} \to x=4$. We use Shell method.

$V = \displaystyle \int_{3}^{2\sqrt{3}} 2\pi x\cdot \dfrac{x}{2}dx + \displaystyle \int_{2\sqrt{3}}^{4} 2\pi x\cdot \left(\dfrac{x}{2} - \sqrt{x^2-12}\right)dx$

Comment: we haven't learnt the shell method as of yet, we have only learnt the slicing method, how would you approach it with the slicing method

Comment: Do you recognize the ring or disk method that I have used?